# Look for a string object from a list in another list

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop

I am doing a little project in which my program unscrambles a string and finds every possible combination of it.

I have two lists; `comboList` and `wordList`. `comboList` holds EVERY combination of the word; for example, the `comboList` for `'ABC'` is:

```
['ABC','ACB','BAC','BCA','CAB','CBA']
```

(Only `'CAB'` is a real word)

`wordList` holds about 56,000 words imported from a text file. These are all found in the English dictionary and sorted by length and then alphabetically.

`isRealWord(comboList,wordList)` is my function to test which words in `comboList` are real by checking if it is in the `wordList`. Here's the code:

```
def isRealWord(comboList, wordList):
    print 'Debug 1'
    for combo in comboList:
        print 'Debug 2'
        if combo in wordList:
           print 'Debug 3'
           print combo
           listOfActualWords.append(combo)
    print 'Debug 4'
```

This is the output:

```
run c:/Users/uzair/Documents/Programming/Python/unscramble.py
Please give a string of scrambled letters to unscramble: abc 
['A', 'B', 'C'] 
['ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA'] 
Loading word list... 
55909 words loaded 
Debug 1 
Debug 2 
Debug 2 
Debug 2 
Debug 2 
Debug 2 
Debug 2 
Debug 4 
[]
```

Why is `if combo in wordList` not returning `True` and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is the wordlist all uppercase, too?

Comment: You could replace your debug 2 line inside your isRealWord method with >> print "{0} : {1}".format(combo, wordList) and see exactly whats being compared -- okay bad debugging - wordList is a tonne of words.. but do print your combo to see exactly what its checking !

Comment: On a side note: using a `set` to hold `wordList` would be much faster! It'd probably even be worth creating the `set` inside of `isRealWord` every time if you need `wordList` to be a `list` in containing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you compare two strings with the same letters but with mixed **lower/upper cases**. 
To see if i'm correct try to convert all word in `wordList` to upper-case and then in `isRealWord` compare with upper-case word (just to be sure) as follows:

```
UpperCaseWordList = [word.upper() for word in wordList]
...
def isRealWord(comboList, wordList):
    for combo.upper() in comboList:
        if combo in wordList:
           print combo
           listOfActualWords.append(combo)
```

Comment: I think you need to change `wordList` parameter to `UpperCaseWordList`

Comment: note that `wordList` is now an argument in a method - so I assumed the call will be like this: `isRealWord(comboList,UpperCaseWordList )`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `set` because it would be much faster due to its implementation. There is `set.intersection` method. Here is a case insensitive solution:

```
listOfActualWords = set.intersection(set(word.upper() for word in comboList), set(word.upper() for word in wordList))
```